# Crear excel de una lista que tiene dentro un diccionario

Tags: python, django, excel

Quisiera saber como crear un archivo de Excel teniendo los datos dentro de una lista que tiene diccionarios anidados en Python.

La estructura de los datos es la siguiente:

```
xs=[{'x': 2, 'y': 1, 'z': 4}, {'x': 3, 'y': 15, 'z': 41}, {'x': 22, 'y': 10, 'z': 40}, {'x': 132, 'y': 89, 'z': 01}]
```

Estoy utilizando la librería ***xlsxwriter*** pero tengo duda de como iterar para conseguir que cada diccionario pase a ser una fila, siendo cada clave una columna.

Es decir, la anterior lista debería dar lugar a la siguiente tabla:

> ```
> ┌─────┬────┬────┐
> │   2 |  1 │  4 │
> ├─────┼────┼────┤
> │   3 │ 15 │ 41 │
> ├─────┼────┼────│
> │  22 │ 10 │ 40 │
> ├─────┼────┼────┤
> │ 132 │ 89 │  1 │ 
> └─────┴────┴────┘
> ```

Comment: Hola David, bievenido a SOes. Podrías seguir el [tour] y [ask] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio. ¿Qué has investigado/intentado? ¿Podrías explicar más en detalle lo que necesitas?

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. La pregunta es demasiado amplia, hay muchas formas y librerías para enfocarla. Deberías buscar primero alguna librería que permita manejar archivos de Excel (xlsxwriter, [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), [openpyxlm](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/), [django-excel](http://django-excel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), etc) y que se adapte mejor a lo que quieres hacer. Si después de intentarlo con alguna tienes problemas añade lo que has intentado y algo más de información (problema concreto que tienes, estructura de tus datos, salida esperada, etc). Saludos.

Comment: ¿David lo que quieres es cada clave sea una fila o una columna? Es decir ¿La primera fila debe ser (2, 1, 4) ó (2, 3, 22, 132)? Si es otra cosa agrega la salida esperada, como debería quedar el excel para la lista que das de ejemplo. Un saludo.

Comment: si la primera fila debe ser 2, 1, 4 la siguiente3, 15, 41 y asi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es básicamente que al tener un diccionario normal, el orden no es preservado. Para que cada dato quede en la celda adecuada debes usar dos `for` y alguna estructura para definir el orden de cada columna.

Una posible solución es usar una lista junto a `enumerate`:

```
import xlsxwriter

xs = [{'x': 2,   'y': 1,  'z': 4}, 
      {'x': 3,   'y': 15, 'z': 41},
      {'x': 22,  'y': 10, 'z': 40},
      {'x': 132, 'y': 89, 'z': 1}]

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('ejemplo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

headers = ['x', 'y', 'z']

for row, _dict in enumerate(xs):
    for col, key in enumerate(headers):
        worksheet.write(row, col, _dict[key])
workbook.close()
```

**Salida:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por el aporte